# How to transform an input to specific component with formControl in Angular

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, typescript

I have a form which work well with a formBuilder, my code is this one :

```
<form *ngIf="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="loginForm">
<div class="div-form">
    <input type="text"
           id="login-input"
           placeholder="{{ (!login.valid && login.touched) ? ('login-input-name-error-required' | translate) : ('login-input-name' | translate) }}"
           formControlName="login"
           [class.error]="!login.valid && login.touched"
    />
</div>
```

with the formBuilder like this login-form.component:

```
 this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        login: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.login = this.loginForm.controls['login'];
    this.password = this.loginForm.controls['password'];
```

But now, when i created a new Input component :

```
<input type="{{type}}"
   id="{{id}}"
   placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
   formControlName="{{formControlName}}"
   [class.error]="errorClassCondition"
   [disabled]="disabled"
   "/>
```

Call like this :

```
        <vic-input
           [type]="'text'"
           [id]="'login-input'"
           [placeholder]="(!login.valid && login.touched) ? ('login-input-name-error-required' | translate) : ('login-input-name' | translate)"
           [formControlName]="login"
           [errorClassCondition]="!login.valid && login.touched"
           [disabled]="true" >
    </vic-input>
```

But i have the following error :`formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).`

I try another method (@viewChild) :
Specific Input

```
<input type="{{type}}"
   id="{{id}}"
   placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
   formControlName="{{formControlName}}"
   [class.error]="errorClassCondition"
   [disabled]="disabled"
   #loginInp
   #loginI="loginForm"
```

/>

With this change in my login-form.component:

```
@ViewChild('loginInput') loginI: ElementRef;

loginForm: FormGroup;
login: AbstractControl;
password: AbstractControl;

private buildAuthenticationForm() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        loginI: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.login = this.loginForm.controls['loginI'];
    this.password = this.loginForm.controls['password'];
}
```

But i have this error in chrome:

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "loginForm" ("
   [disabled]="disabled"
   #loginInp
   [ERROR ->]#loginI="loginForm"
```

Is there a way to do what i want with the formBuilder without using ng.model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this message:

> formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. 
>   You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing
>   FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Perhaps you need something like this:

```
<div formGroup="loginGroup">
        <vic-input
           [type]="'text'"
           [id]="'login-input'"
           [placeholder]="(!login.valid && login.touched) ? ('login-input-name-error-required' | translate) : ('login-input-name' | translate)"
           [formControlName]="login"
           [errorClassCondition]="!login.valid && login.touched"
           [disabled]="true" >
    </vic-input>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,there is already a formGroup in the form : <form *ngIf="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="loginForm">                                        and it's works without the input component

Comment: `formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.` can you try remove that `vic-input` middleware and try again? Perhaps formControlName expects formGroup directive it first parent....

Comment: In fact the vic-input replace the input in my first block of code, and without it it's works good

Comment: If you use input exactly - its ok, right? If you use input through vicInput - its not ok, right?

Comment: Well looks like its ok to have middleware like vicInput: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#question-form-components

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link. In fact my problem was i used the magic word formControlName as an Input variable in the call of the vic-input.  Changing the name in controlName works better.

Comment: Oh true. But you don't have [] around it.... Why angular treats it as a directive. I will update my answer.